# expo camera not saving picture to gallery - why is this so hard?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

- I can take a picture and it'll even show a preview afterwards but it won't save it to the gallery.
- after I add the `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync` it won't even show the image preview after taking a picture and still doesn't save into the gallery (or any local storage).

I don't know where I'm going wrong here for days now. Please any tips or hints would be great.

```
   //imports
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
  
   // useState
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [rollPermision, setRollPermission] = useState(null);

 // useEffect and ref to the camera
  const cameraRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === "granted");
      // camera roll
        const { cam_roll } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        setRollPermission(cam_roll === "granted");
        setRollPermission(true);
    }
    )();
  }, []);

// shutter button function to take picture
  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, skipProcessing: true };
      const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
      //camera roll (saving picture)
      const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(data);

      const source = asset.uri;
      if (source) {
        await cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
        setIsPreview(true);
        console.log("picture source", source);
      }
    }
  };


 //if statement if it hit an error
      if (hasPermission === null || rollPermision === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false || rollPermision === false) {
    return <Text style={styles.text}>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
      //camera roll (saving picture)
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(data);
```

Should be:

```
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(data.uri);
 or
    const { uri } = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
```

You have to save data.uri instead of data itself. If you console.log(data) you will see that its an object that contains the uri of the image stored in cache.

Comment: omg `const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(data.uri);` worked! why did it have to be `data.uri`? I'm so confused by that because the documentation kept saying that it's a localUri and even in their example when they called the camera `uri` and called it within the `createAssetAsync` I did it but I had changed the string `uir` to `data`. Seems like the actual work `uri` was needed.

Comment: Data is an object that contains the following information about the image:  { uri, width, height, exif, base64 }. In the example in the docs, they use ES6's  dereferencing to extract the uri directly from the returned object. const { uri } = ... So, it can be a little confusing at time.Anyway, glad I could be of help.